# Tricky CSS Layout for same height

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, css-grid

there's a tricky layout I'd like to create. I am starting to think that javascript would be needed to complete this.The non-complete version is here:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/beaversArePeopleToo/pen/dyrBNVb?editors=1100) .

```
    <article>
        <div>
            <div class='title'>Consigli</div>
            <p>Strumento militare puo portare traumi. Soluzioni di continuita' che non fanno bene.</p>
       </div>
       <div>
       <div class='title'>Bambino dalla finestra per intervenire sarebbe stata troppo umana</div>
           <p>Wisconsin is a state in the Upper Midwestern region of the United States. It borders Minnesota to the west, Iowa to the southwest, Illinois to the south, Lake Michigan to the east, Michigan to the northeast, and Lake Superior to the north. Wisconsin is the 25th-largest state by land area and the 20th-most populous.</p>
        </div>
    </article>
```

- I'd like all the columns to have the title of the same height, like in the picture below, that is, setting the height to the height of the tallest title
- Moreover, I'd like its width to be responsive and go into a new row when needed
- And also I'd like the column's text to be of same height, like in the picture below

[image: how it should look like]